# How to customize and personalize a jsf pages without ADF MDS?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, oracle-adf, oracle-mds

I'am using Jdeveloper(12.1.2 & 12.1.3) since 2 years and untill now i use ADF MDS to **customize and personalize my jsf pages**.

Now i have to "**customize and personalize my jsf pages**" without ADF.

My questions:

1. Is there a tools or framework which could help me to solv my issue?
2. Does somebody deal already with this issue?
3. What it's JSF own approach on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "customize and personalize"?

Comment: enable or disabled component. Skinning etc. Do you know how ADF MDS works?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent declarative way of doing this in JSF - you'll have to write Java code that will do all of this for you and change your pages at runtime - Why wouldn't you use MDS for this?

Comment: Till now, we are using MDS to solv this issue. We have a very huge projet and there is not enough ADF Developer on the market. So are thinking about ADF alternatives and one of the choice is JSF where you could find plenty developer around the world.